# Get WPF button status in real time in Powershell for long running event

Tags: wpf, powershell, event-handling

I am trying to change checkbox content property during its execution. If **Test1** is selected and button clicked it should show immediately **Test 1 Running** (same applies for **Test2** if selected). Once test finishes it should show **Test 1 finished**. Right now there are no interim changes until button task completes which ends with **Test 1 finished**. I was reading about WPF Toolkit BusyIndicator (cannot implement as it is closed network where I am running this) and also async-await but not sure how to implement solution powershell/xaml way.

```
Add-type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, PresentationCore

$ToolboxXml = @"
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Toolbox"
WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
Height ="300"
Width ="250"
Topmost="True"
FontFamily="Arial"
WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="30 10 30 0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="vertical">
            <CheckBox Name="chkbx1"  Content="Test1"/>
            <CheckBox Name="chkbx2"  Content="Test2"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="button1"  Content="Run Tests"/>
            <Label Name="label2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$ToolboxGui = $ToolboxXml -replace "x:N",'N'

$Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse(([string]$ToolboxGui))
[xml]$xaml = $ToolboxGui
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]").ForEach{
    Set-Variable  -Name $_.Name -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -Force
}

$label2.content = "Test(s) not running"

$button1.add_Click({
    If ($chkbx1.IsChecked){
       $Script:chkbx1.content = "Test 1 Running"
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
       $Script:chkbx1.content = "Test 1 Finished"
    }
    If ($chkbx2.IsChecked){
       $Script:chkbx2.content = "Test 2 Running"
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
       $Script:chkbx2.content = "Test 2 Finished"
    }
    $Script:label2.content = "Tests Finished"
})

[void]$Script:label2 

$async = $Form.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync({
    $Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
})
$async.Wait() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Well, if you're looking to update the button content, you should be using `$button1.Content` and not `$Script:chkbx2.content`.

Comment: My bad I meant checkbox property.

Comment: You need to sleep on a background thread. The same thread cannot noth update the `CheckBox` and sleep or doing somethin else simultaneously.

Comment: Start-Sleep here is just to simulate long running event.

Comment: mm8 is right. For that kind of behavior u need a background job for example beginInvoke.